# Excircle and circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

$$ \triangle ABC$$
$k(O; R)$ circumscribed, $P$ is the midpoint of arc $AB$

$O_1$ is the centre of the excircle of $\triangle ABC$, touching the side AB.
Show that $PA = PB = PO_1$.

---

I tried to prove that $\triangle APO_1$ (or $\triangle BPO_1$) is isosceles, but I can't figure it out. I will be very grateful if you help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this can be divided into 2 stages:

1. Show that $P$ lies on $CO_1$.
2. Angle chasing

For the first stage, connect $CO_1$, name the intersection of $CO_1$ and arc $AB$ be $P'$. Apparently, $CO_1$ is the bisector of $∠MCN$, so $∠ACP'=∠P'CB$. Also, since $∠ACP=∠PCB$, we can deduce that $P'$ overlaps with $P$. So $P$ is on $CO_1$, and $PA=PB$.

For the second stage, start from $∠MAP=∠CBP$. With $∠MAO_1=∠QAO_1$, $∠PAB=∠PBA$, we can rewrite the equality to $∠QAO_1+∠PAO_1=∠CBA+∠PAB$, which can be reduced to $2∠PAO_1=∠CBA$. And since $∠CBA=∠CPA$, we can then deduce $∠CPA=2∠PAO_1$, which is the same as saying $∠PAO_1=∠PO_1A$. Therefore $PA=PO_1$.

Hence $PA=PB=PO_1$ is shown.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But why $\angle MAP = \angle CBP$?

Comment: This is a property of concyclic quadrilateral. The exterior angle of an interior angle of a concyclic quadrilateral is equal to the opposite interior angle.

Comment: I haven't studied that. I will be very grateful if you can explain to me how to show it.

Comment: Connect CP.  ∠MAP = ∠ACP + ∠ABP. ∠ACP = ∠ABP, ∠APC = ∠ABC, so ∠MAP = ∠CBP

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I really don't understand why $\angle MAP = \angle ACP + \angle ABP$. Maybe this is a property of concyclic  quadrilateral, but I don't know them as I said.

Comment: I am sorry about my typo error, but the first equality should be ∠MAP = ∠ACP + ∠APC instead of ∠MAP = ∠ACP + ∠ABP

Comment: Thank you! I understood the solution. Can you tell me what is the most important thing in this problem? (how did you get your idea?; how did you start?)

Comment: I would say that the most important step is the first step, which is to realise that $C$, $P$ and $O_1$ are collinear. Only after establishing that fact can I then comfortably do the angle chasing to derive the desired result. To be frank, I think I got by "luck", by being "greedy" to want to prove something extra. It also actually looks like they are collinear, so I went on to try to see if it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let I, J be the in-center and ex-center respectively.

[image]

Note that C, I, P are collinear and C, I, J are also collinear. Then, CIPJ are on the same straight line.

"$\angle AIP = ... = \angle ABJ$" implies AIBJ is cyclic.

"$IB \bot JB$" implies IPJ is the diameter of the circle AIBJ.

The perpendicular bisector of chord AB cuts CPJ at P. This means P is the center of AIBJ.